# All MediaElements are not playing

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

For some reason only a couple of the sounds attached to the Media Elements are playing. The code runs and hits everything properly but not all the sounds will play. All the media elements are in the XAML and are set as Content, copy if newer.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Margin="0,-1,0,0">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="85"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="615*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Head" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Electronic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="60" RenderTransformOrigin="0.567,0.259" Height="85" Width="283" Foreground="#FF1BA1E2"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFE9E9E9">
            <telerikPrimitives:RadUniformGrid NumberOfColumns="1" NumberOfRows="8">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Aftershock" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Aftershock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Conga" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Conga" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Fever" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Fever" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Lightspeed" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Lightspeed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Remember" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Remember" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Synth" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Synth" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="Viper" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Tap="Button_Tap_1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Stroke="#FF1BA1E2" Width="75" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/AppBar/Transport.Play.png"/>
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Viper" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontSize="35" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
                </StackPanel>
             </telerikPrimitives:RadUniformGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="AftershockSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Aftershock.mp3"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="CongaSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Conga.mp3"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="FeverSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Fever.mp3"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="LightspeedSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Lightspeed.mp3"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="RememberSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Remember.mp3"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="SynthSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Synth.mp3"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="ViperSound" AutoPlay="False" Source="/Assets/Sounds/Electronic/Viper.mp3"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
    private void Button_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var button = sender as Button;
        string alarmName = button.Name;

        switch (alarmName)
        {
            case "Aftershock":
                AftershockSound.Stop();
                AftershockSound.Play();
                break;
            case "Conga":
                CongaSound.Stop();
                CongaSound.Play();
                break;
            case "Fever":
                FeverSound.Stop();
                FeverSound.Play();
                break;
            case "Lightspeed":
                LightspeedSound.Stop();
                LightspeedSound.Play();
                break;
            case "RememberSound":
                RememberSound.Stop();
                RememberSound.Play();
                break;
            case "SynthSound":
                SynthSound.Stop();
                SynthSound.Play();
                break;
            case "Viper":
                ViperSound.Stop();
                ViperSound.Play();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle MediaOpened event for all audio files and make sure that you call stop/play method after MediaOpened event is raised.

Comment: Sorry but would you be able to give me an example of what you're suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: xaml....    <MediaElement x:Name="AftershockSound" MediaOpened="AftershockSound_MediaOpend"  ...>


.cs

private void AftershockSound_MediaOpend(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){//Make sure that this event is raised before you call pay for the media element}

Comment: For some reason, it's not being raised for some sounds. Any ideas why?

Comment: Than Double check sound paths and set build status to content-copy always(just to make sure)

Comment: by the way why not use only one media element? as at one time only one audio will be playing. so just one media element and load one .mp3 file and on MediaOpened event handler play that adio. it might solve your issue. if you need example let me know

Comment: Your suggestions and setting autoplay to true did the trick!  Thanks for the help!